# Will Math Ever Stop Using Paper?

Tags: education, math-history, article-writing

This is an odd question, yet I must still inquire: will math ever stop using paper? In the writing industry, paper is dead; we do all our writing on computers. Yet with all of mathematics' complex symbols and equations, I don't doubt that we *must* continue to write them out on paper. Writing is so efficient on computers, but math equations are slow and monotonous to type out. At the same time, are there better ways to do math?

EDIT: According to some of these comments, I should have been more clear. I do indeed mean *before* the earth is swallowed up by the sun.

Comment: You mean, before or after the heat death of the universe?

Comment: Ever heard of $\LaTeX$?

Comment: @TheGeekGreek Knowledge of LaTeX does not imply that you no longer make all your fast scribbling and graphics on your paper napkin during lunch ...

Comment: The obvious loophole to this question is tablet computers: use a stylus, a touchscreen tablet, and handwriting recognition software (such as that bundled with Microsoft Word), and writing equations no longer happens "on paper", so to speak.

Comment: For beginners, there is real value in practicing drawing graphs such as $y = x^3 - 3 x$ by hand, on graph paper. It gives concrete meaning to later calculus studies.

Comment: Certainly as long as I live I will use paper for sketching and rough work before typing it up. I also use paper for my writing as well to make outlines and organize my thoughts. Math was done before paper existed though and I don't see it being required, just useful.

Comment: I don’t even agree with your statement about writers. The writers that I know have notebooks and notebooks full of ideas and quotes and all sorts of tidbits that help them while writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematics isn't particularly unique on this front.

While professional writers are often typing out their work and yet occasionally when you are driven to jot down an inspired idea you just reach for the closest writing instrument. Computer, Napkin, Journal, your hand, whatever. 
My experience has been that professional mathematicians are very much the same way. All communication between professionals is basically typed. The symbols required are not really much of an issue given our typesetting languages. We use latex here (And so do all mathematicians really) and I can produce the oddest of symbols pretty darn quickly.

$$\int_0^r{(r^m-x^m)^{1/m}dx}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{m}+1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{m}+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{m}+1\right)}r^2$$

Integrals and greek letters are pretty tame in comparison to what the technology is capable of...

Anyway just like the writing industry the fact that we CAN communicate very efficiently via computers doesn't really stop most mathematicians from asking the waiter for a pen so we can jot a thought down on the back of a napkin before the thought is lost into the ether...

Paper writing isn't going away for either discipline. But correspondence is now almost exclusive digital for both disciplines.